# Stop string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, avr, uart

How to stop sting array. If I set maximum 40 char that can be put, but I dont want to fill the whole string with 40 char. Here are my code for write char at string array.

```
int main(void)
 {

    char data[1][40];   
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
        serial_init();

        while (1)
    {

        for (i1=0;i1<1;i1++) 
            { 
               for (i2=0;i2<40;i2++) 
               { 
                  data[i1][i2] = Usart_Receive(); 
               } 
            } 

           for (i1=0;i1<1;i1++) 
           { 
               for (i2=0;i2<40;i2++) 
               { 
                  Usart_Transmit(data[i1][i2]); 
               } 
           }       

      }  
    return 0;   
}
```

Example If I push `if (Usart_Receive() == '.')`. It function as stop the string to fill until 40 char. How to do that, I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: c strings are null terminated, so the simple approach is to make that inner loop while(data[i1][i2++] = Usart_Receive()) and write that char getting function to return 0 when the input is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (i1=0;i1<1;i1++) 
        { 
           for (i2=0;i2<40;i2++) 
           { 
              data[i1][i2] = Usart_Receive(); 
              if (data[i1][i2] == '.') {
                  if (i2 < 39) data[i1][i2+1] = '\0';  // null terminate string
                  break
              }
           } 
        }
```

This will stop receive on '.', null terminate the string (if needed), and break out of the loop.

Comment: `data[i1][i2+1] == '\0';` : Meaningless conditional.

Comment: No, `data[i1][i2+1] == '\0'` is a perfectly correct conditional, the problem is it was intended as an assignment instead of a conditional ;-) Good catch, fixed in answer.

Comment: also `data[i1][i2+1] = '\0';` is unsafe.

Comment: What of this?: `data[i1][i2+1] = 0;`, and your 'safer' method is? Perhaps examples instead of unclad criticism would be more educational for all involved.

Comment: range of `i2` is 0-39. 
It is beyond the scope of the sequences is a condition in the case of 39.(e.g. `data[i1][i2+1] = '\0';` -> `data[i1][39+1(40)] = '\0';`)

Comment: Grrr. Crow tastes awful. Fixed.

Comment: it can not be said that a good way because it does not guarantee a null terminate.

Comment: I want to ask you guys, the example that you gave is just at the receive, how about at the transmit part, I want to send the string exactly same as the receive part when the `'.'` is press. thank!

Comment: What concerns me here is you want to send when the `'.'` is pressed. How are you taking character input? Are you accepting input in raw/unbuffered mode using something like `select`? Let us see the input code and we can take a look. If you haven't finished it yet, take a look at this implementation `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=554845`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I will take a look at this implementation. Right now I online using my phone, I will take a look when I reach house. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    int main(void)
       {
        char data[1][40];   
        int i1 = 0;
        serial_init();
        while (1)
        {
        while (1)
        {
         data[0][i1] = '?'; //Add whatever You want 
         char received = Usart_Receive();
         if(received != '.'){
                    data[0][i1] = received;             
             }
            i1++;
            if(i1>40){
             break;
            }
         }
       i1 = 0;
       while (1)
         {
            Usart_Transmit(data[0][i2]);
            i1++;
            if(i1>40){
             break;
            }
         }
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

This adds char to your array if received is not equals to '.'.Also fills char upto 40 char to your array.

Comment: `i1>40` : this is wrong. It is too late.